# PHP - Avoiding nested if statements - cleaner way to code this

Tags: php, if-statement, nested

Assume that I am creating a registration form.   I have code like the below and it is hard to manage because of all the nested if statements.

I want to know the cleanest and easiest to follow way to write code that functions similarly to what I have below.

**EDIT**: People have told me that I can move the empty($_POST['email']) to the validation functions.   I can't do that because I need to know 1) whether user has posted data or not, and 2) whether the data user posted is valid.

For example, when the user first goes to the registration page, they have not posted any data so $_POST['email'] will generate PHP warnings because they don't exist.  That's why I check whether data has been posted before I validate.

Does this make sense?

```
function validate_email($str) {
    $str = trim(strtolower($str));
    if(!filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return $str;
    }
}

function validate_password($str) {
    $str = trim($str);
    if(strlen($str) < 5 || strlen($str) > 70) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

$email = false;
$password = false;
$errorMessage = false;

if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = validate_email($_POST['email']);
    if($email) {
        if(!empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $password = validate_password($_POST['password']);
            if($password) {
                createNewUser($email,$password);
            } else {
                $errorMessage = "The password is not valid";
            }
        } else {
            $errorMessage = "The password is not valid";
        }
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "Email address is invalid";
    }
} else {
    $errorMessage = "Email address is invalid";
}

if($errorMessage) echo $errorMessage;
```

Comment: Theres nothing really wrong with that, there may be a neater way but it probably won't be as fast

Comment: it's not like speed is any issue with such code. The only real concern here is readibility.

Comment: @AdamTester Code being maintainable has much higher priority then a little gain in speed. Which probably will be not noticable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `empty` checks at that point, move them to the validation functions.

For example:

```
function validate_email($str) {
    if(empty($str)) {
      return false;
    }

    $str = trim(strtolower($str));
    if(!filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return $str;
    }
}

$email = validate_email($_POST['email']);
if($email) { 
  // your code
}
```

Comment: +1 Exactly what went through my mind when reading the code. I also wan't to add that having a cap on a password length is not a very good choice. Seventy is a high enough number but users shouldn't be restricted in wanting a longer password.

Comment: Well, that's not really part of the question though, so I didn't touch on it.

Comment: remark from me: first trim, then check if is empty (prevents data input full of spaces)

Comment: @Bart As far as the length of password, in practice, 70 will not be an issue, but more importantly, I thought I read somewhere that above 72 characters actually created less security with one of the php hashing functions I looked at.   I don't remember where I read this and didn't understand the details but an fyi

Comment: I edited my question above.   I need to know whether user has posted data or not and I need to separately know whether the data posted was okay.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you have nested `if()`s you can flip the logic "inside out":

```
if (A)
  if (B)
    if (C)
      final()
```

change to:

```
 if (!A) return
 if (!B) return
 if (!C) return
 final()
```

In your case instead of returning you could throw an exception.

```
try {
  validateAndCreateNewUser();
}
catch(ValidationError $e) {
  display($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use exceptions to handle normal flow control. I agree with the first point however; the "single exit point" argument seems to be blindly adhered to (by some) without valid reason.

Comment: @cbuckley what is exceptional is angles-on-a-pin debate. In this case flow control is simple, and the pattern is not surprising (`ValidationException` is in [.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationerror.aspx), [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/), [JavaX](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/ValidationException.html), Grails… etc.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit cleaner:

```
function validate_email($str) {
    if (empty($str)) return false;
    $str = trim(strtolower($str));
    if(!filter_var($str, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return $str;
    }
}

function validate_password($str) {
    if (empty($str)) return false;
    $str = trim($str);
    if(strlen($str) < 5 || strlen($str) > 70) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return $str;
    }
}

$email = false;
$password = false;
$errorMessage = false;

$email = validate_email($_POST['email']);
if($email) {
    $password = validate_password($_POST['password']);
    if($password) {
        createNewUser($email,$password);
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "The password is not valid";
    }
} else {
    $errorMessage = "Email address is invalid";
}

if($errorMessage) echo $errorMessage;
```